# Find the minimum value of $|1-1.1y+0.8x|$.

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Given $x\le 5$ and $y>5$. I want to minimize th function $|1-1.1y+0.8x|$.

By trial my assumption is $|1-1.1y+0.8x|>0.5$. But I am unable to prove this.

If I'm right then how to prove this ? If I'm wrong then what will be the minimum value ?

Any help plase ?

Comment: Can be solved in different ways, depending on what topic you are currently covering. You could plot the inequalities and use linear optimization. Does this help?

Comment: @bananapeel22 I want simplest algebraic way.. no need to exact lower bound..at least a rough (positive) lower bound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $x\le 5$ and $y>5$. Let $$F=1-1.1y+0.8x$$

$$y>5 \implies -1.1y<-5.5$$
and $$x\le 5\implies 0.8x\le 4$$

So $$F<1-5.5+4 =-0.5\implies |F|>0.5$$

Comment: Sorry! My mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Here is another elementary way:

Set

$$y=5+t \text{ with } t\gt 0 \text{ and } x=5-s \text{ with } s\geq 0$$

That way you get:

\begin{eqnarray*} |1-1.1y+0.8x|
& = & |-0.5 - 1.1t-0.8s| \\
& \stackrel{t>0, s\geq 0}{=} & 0.5 + 1.1t + 0.8 s \\
& > & 0.5
\end{eqnarray*}